# Axon How can I add an event listener/interceptor to intercept events before they reach their handlers?

Tags: spring, domain-driven-design, interceptor, event-sourcing, axon

I have a projection class (to build a read model) and I want to add an interceptor for its events in a way that if the id passed in the event leads to a null object (non-existent in my db) then I want to block it, otherwise let it pass.

This way I will escape adding a null checker on EVERY event handler.

```
@EventHandler
public void onEvent(Event event) {
    Entity entity = getEntity(event.getId());
    if(entity!=null){        // what I don't want to add on every event handler
        dostuff();
    }
}
```

I found that axon provides an interface called [EventListener](https://axoniq.io/apidocs/3.0/org/axonframework/eventhandling/EventListener.html) but I'm not sure how to work with it and I'm not sure if this will be intercepting ALL of my events or if I will be able to intercept select events.

There is no mention anywhere for this interface but in the official documentation (with no actual examples or so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right on the part the the Reference Guide still needs some improvements @bleh10 - I can assure you, they're being worked on, the team is just spread out relatively thin.

In absence of the sought after example, I think I can give you some guidance.

What you're looking for is a `MessageHandlerInterceptor` implementation, specifically for the `EventMessage` type. As the naming suggests, it intercepts messages prior to being handled, which corresponds perfectly with the question you've posed.

Secondly, you obviously need a place to configure these. Within an Axon application, the technical aspect of delivering events to your `@EventHandler` annotated methods, is the Event Processor. As such, it is in charge of ensuring the Event Messages flowing through it are intercepted as desired.

Hence, the place to configure your `EventMessage` `MessageHandlerInterceptor`, is on the `EventProcessor` implementation you've chosen. To ensure a given Event Handling Component is set in a specific `EventProcessor`, you can specify it's Processing Group by annotating the class with the `@ProcessingGroup` annotation.

From there on, you can easily configure specific properties for your Event Processor by utilizing the `EventProcessingConfigurer`. More specifically, I'd suggest to use the `EventProcessingConfigurer#registerHandlerInterceptor(String, Function<Configuration, MessageHandlerInterceptor<? super EventMessage<?>>>)` method for this.

The first `String` parameter is meant to describe the name of your Processing Group. The second is a `Function` which receive the Axon `Configuration` and should output a `MessageHandlerInterceptor` which can deal with the `EventMessage` class.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I finally had the time to try it out and it did work smoothly. Sadly setting the @processingGroup led to axon replying the events which caused some issues

Comment: No worries @bleh10, happy that it resolved the problem in the end. And bummer, I should've warned you about that. Technically, changing the processing group, especially to a new one, let's the framework thing a brand new Tracking Event Processor was introduced, which by default will start from the head of the stream...You can change where the Tracking Token starts if you want by the way, through the `TrackingEventProcessorConfiguration#andInitialTrackingToken()`. The `StreamableMessageSource` in the provided function can be used to create a head or tail token. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply as always, and it's fine everything is back up working properly. I will keep this option in mind if we need it later on!

Comment: No worries, I am glad to help! :-)